# Cancel Operations / UI Notification and UI Information?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm currently working on a small project that use Tasks.Dataflow and I'm a little bit confused about UI notifications. I want to separate my "Pipeline" from the UI in another class called `PipelineService`, but I'm unable to notify the UI on cancelled operations or data that should be shown up in the UI. How can this be handled in the right manner?

Code:

```
    private void btnStartPipeline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStartPipeline.Enabled = false;
        btnStopPipeline.Enabled = true;

        cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = pipeline.SearchPipeline();        
        }

        head.Post(AppDirectoryNames.STORE_PATH);
    }

    private void btnStopPipeline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationToken.Cancel();
    }
```

This methods related to `Form1.cs`. `head` is type of `ITargetBlock<string>`.

```
    public ITargetBlock<string> SearchPipeline()
    { 
        var search = new TransformBlock<string, IEnumerable<FileInfo>>(path =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return Search(path);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<FileInfo>();
                }
            });

        var move = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<FileInfo>>(files =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Move(files);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            });

        var operationCancelled = new ActionBlock<object>(delegate
            {

                form.Invoke(form._update);
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
            });

        search.LinkTo(move);

        search.LinkTo(operationCancelled);

        return search;
    }
```

`Invoke` don't take effect with delegate methods. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you even have the `catch` there? It doesn't do anything useful. And if you want to rethrow an exception, use just `throw;`, not `throw ex;`, because the latter resets the stack trace, which makes the exception more difficult to debug.

Comment: The catch block handles the cancellation and passing it to the next stage of the pipeline. This is also related to a reference implementation on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228605

Comment: No, it doesn't. The reference implementation doesn't rethrow the exception anywhere. The way you're doing it is just redundant, the `catch` is useless. And there is no “next stage” after an `ActionBlock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I din't understand why you think your code should work. The way you set up your dataflow network, each `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` generated by the `search` block is first sent to the `move` block. If the `move` block didn't accept it (which never happens here), it would be sent to the `operationCancelled` block. That doesn't seem to be what you want at all.

After looking at [the walkthough you seem to be basing your code on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228605), it does cancellation similar than you, but with one significant difference: it uses `LinkTo()` with a predicate, which rejects a message that signifies cancellation. If you wanted to do the same, you would need to also use `LinkTo()` with a predicate. And since I don't think an empty sequence is a good choice to signify cancellation, I think you should switch to `null` too.

Also, you don't need to use `form.Invoke()` if you're already using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`, they do basically the same thing.

```
public ITargetBlock<string> SearchPipeline()
{ 
    var search = new TransformBlock<string, IEnumerable<FileInfo>>(path =>
        {
            try
            {
                return Search(path);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        });

    var move = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<FileInfo>>(files =>
        {
            try
            {
                Move(files);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // swallow the exception; we don't want to fault the block
            }
        });

    var operationCancelled = new ActionBlock<object>(_ => form._update(),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        });

    search.LinkTo(move, files => files != null);

    search.LinkTo(operationCancelled);

    return search;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. I will give it a try in a few hours. :)

Comment: hm, i'm still running into problems to get the ui responding to activities in the `PipelineService` class, like messages from stages in the pipeline. sometimes there is no reaction or `Illegal Cross Thread Operation`, narf.